# Can't bind variable to select Query Builder on Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I can't bind variable to `DB::select()` but can't tell what I'm doing wrong.

Below is my code;

```
$id = 1;
return DB::select('SELECT
    a.id,
    a.tender_name, (SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM
    merging_vendor_project
WHERE
    planning_id=a.id) as count_participants
FROM
    planning as a
WHERE a.id=?',[$id]);
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do via an SQL statement can easily be done by Laravel's Eloquent.

First lets create the Model:

```
php artisan make:model Planning
```

Following conventions, we don't use `Planning` but more like `Plan` but for the simplicity sake I will use `Planning`.

```
class Planning extends Model
{
    public $table = 'planning'

    public function merging_vendor_project(){
       return $this->hasMany(MergeVendorProject::class)
    }
}
```

Now you can a simple `withCount` on the model like:

```
$id = 1
Planning::where('id', $id)->select('id', 'name', 'tender_name', 'merging_vendor_project_count')->withCount('merging_vendor_project')->get();
```

Boom... There you go. You have your inital query made in `Laravel style`. Taylor Otwell would be proud of you for using Eloquent and not `DB::select`